# parseKML in Earth API for Maps v3

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am new to maps v3 and is seeking help for the following items:

1. Strugging to find an example for parseKML in google maps v3. There is similar example which works for Earth API on code playground.
   http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/#parse_kml.
   I tried geoxml3 library too but it appears that this only support URL input and not actual XML content.
2. I have a KML file which extracts point data from a web coverage service. This service returns a KML on the fly and I have it displayed on Earth API. I've been testing this feature on maps v3 but it's not working. I tried opening the KML file on maps.google.com but the content only show up if you switch to Earth interface. Is this a limitation of Maps v3 API for I should be doing something differently.

http://maps.google.com/maps?q=http:%2F%2Fwww.mde.state.md.us%2Fprograms%2FAir%2FAirQualityMonitoring%2FDocuments%2FDomain3.kml&hl=en&ll=38.369651,-77.064842&spn=3.303117,3.724365&sll=37.0625,-95.677068&sspn=52.815565,59.589844&t=m&z=8

Thank you so much for any help.

Comment: geoxml3 does (now) support parsing valid KML as a string. See the parseKmlString method.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried validating your KML on the interactive sampler. If it works there on Google Earth , then it should work on google maps too.

https://kml-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/interactive/index.html